# Add Translucent Image to JLayeredPane

Tags: java, image, swing, transparent, layer

So I'm making a stopmotion application - the live feed from my webcam is inside a JPanel (with setOpaque(false)) that is inside the top (10th) layer in a JLayeredPane - and basically, when I take a picture, I want to add it to one of the lower layers so that a trace of the previous pictures you've taken shows up on screen.  Here's how I'm trying to do that now:

EDIT: this is my *new* code based off the answer below - this now does nothing, as opposed to just adding the opaque image as before - if I add this to a JPanel, though, and add the JPanel to the JLayeredPane, then all I get is gray

```
BufferedImage img2 = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g = img2.createGraphics();
g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, .5f));              

g.drawImage(img2, 0, 0, null);
g.dispose(); 

ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(img2).getImage().getScaledInstance(img2.getWidth(), img2.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
JLabel showPic = new JLabel(imgIcon);
showPic.setSize(layers.getSize());
showPic.setBounds(layers.getX() + 18, layers.getY(), img2.getWidth(), img2.getHeight());

layers.add(showPic, new Integer(1)); //layers is my JLayeredPane
layers.repaint();
layers.revalidate();
```

img is the picture I've just captured from my webcam, and I'm trying to make it semi transparent, then add it to a JLabel.  How can I make this work?  Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will solve the problem but the image you are looking for is

```
BufferedImage img2 = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
```

java.awt.Transparency.TRANSLUCENT has the value of 3 and corresponds to BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE which only god knows what it's doing.

With BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB you can create a transparent image and apply Composite etc

You also need to correct this

```
g.drawImage(img2, null, 0, 0);
```

to

```
g.drawImage(img2, 0, 0, null);
```

--

Heres how transparency works for me:

I have two images bim and bim2 and I draw one on top of the other:

```
BufferedImage bim=null, bim2=null;
try {
  bim=ImageIO.read(new File("...."));
  bim2=ImageIO.read(new File("...."));
}
catch (Exception ex) { System.err.println("error in bim "+ex); }
int wc=bim.getWidth(), hc=bim.getHeight();

BufferedImage img2 = new BufferedImage(bim.getWidth(), bim.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g = img2.createGraphics();
g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, .5f));              

g.drawImage(bim, 0, 0, null);
g.drawImage(bim2, 0, 0, wc, hc, null);
```

Then I can display it on a JPanel Jframe or whatever.

I can even create the Label:

```
JLabel showPic = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img2));
JFrame f=new JFrame();
f.setSize(500, 500);
f.add(showPic);
f.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Got it - only now when I add it, nothing shows up - unless I add it to a JPanel, in which case (after I do panel.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0, 50)) only grey shows up on the screen.  Is it not possible in a JLayeredPane to make an upper layer transparent and to see the layer underneath?

Comment: now I notice: you need to have another image you cant be drawing an empty image (img2) on to itself - what is the image from the webcam?

Comment: The image from the webcam is called img - although I'm not trying to modify that, as I'm storing it somewhere else intact - I'd like to make a copy of img and then make this copy semi-transparent

Comment: ok if you try my approach you can draw the ten images on top of each other (or keep a list of them and draw them in reverse if thats what you like) - then replace the newer images on the list - good luck

Comment: It says to avoid comments like these, but: GOD BLESS YOU IT WORKS